# VScode not showing php extension PDO,mysqli functions for autocomplete

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, mysqli, pdo

I'm trying to learn backend technologies using PHP MySQL, so when I'm using vscode it only suggests to me the basics PHP functions,
[image]

but when I use the PDO or mysqli it's not showing me any suggestions in order to make autocomplete or give you info about a specific function

[image]

Comment: FYI please don't use the obsolete mysqli_real_escape_string - you should be using prepared statements and parameters for this kind of thing. This has been the case for almost 20 years.

Comment: well, that is interesting.... but I'm asking why vscode not showing the PHP extension like PDO or mysqli functions